# Checking String Content with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

I've got myself a project where I have to determine if a string contains a set string.
Example:
What I'm looking for `website.com`
What is might look like `jsngsowebsite.comadfjubj`

So far my own endevours have yielded this:

```
titletxt = document.getElementById('title');
titlecheck=titletxt.IndexOf("website.com");

if (titlecheck>=0) {
  return false;
}
```

Which doesn't seem to be doing the trick, any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

```
function text( el ) {
    return el.innerText ? el.innerText : el.textContent;
}

function contains( substring, string ) {
    return string.indexOf(substring)>=0
}

contains( 'suggestions', text( document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0] ) )
```

Replace `suggestions` and `document.getElements...` with a string and a DOM element reference.

```
titlecheck=titletxt.IndexOf("website.com");
```

That looks like you're trying to use the `IndexOf` ( lowercase the `I` ) on a DOM element which won't even have that method, the text is inside the `textContent` ( standard DOM property ) or `innerText` ( IE specific property ).

Comment: the contains function should be >= 0 - but otherwise +1 for pointing out the innerText of a DOM element

Comment: thanks - slipped my mind, though innerText is IE DOM specific.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript functions are case sensitive - `indexOf` not `IndexOf`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `indexOf()` method:

```
title = "lalalawebsite.comkkk";
```

`indexOf` returns `-1` if the string `"website.com"` isn't found in `title`

```
titlecheck = title.indexOf("website.com") > 0 ? "found" : "not found";

alert(titlecheck);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use String.match(...)

```
title = document.getElementById('title');
titletxt = title.innerText ? title.innerText : title.textContent
titlecheck = titletxt.match("website.com");

 if (titlecheck != null ) {
   return false;
 }
```

String.match returns null if no match is found, and returns the search string("website.com") if a match is found